# C++ - Can a vector's size become more than the system RAM?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, out-of-memory

If I keep on inserting elements in a vector until I get an out of memory exception.
What is the limit to the final vector's size?

1. Size of RAM
2. Size of secondary memory because virtual memory is being used.

Comment: Often (3) whatever per-process or per-user virtual memory limit your operating system has configured.

Comment: Yes, a vector's size can become more than system RAM on an operating system that supports virtual memory.  Many operating systems over-promise memory, such that when an application allocates memory the OS over commits, and only when the application asks to use the memory that was previously allocated that the memory access faults.  The upshot being, on such operating systems, out-of-memory situation may not be something that can be handled within the process.

Comment: @Eljay: Though if you are "inserting elements" then the memory is going to be used right away.  The result of overcommit would then be that you get a deadly signal instead of a C++ exception.

Comment: @NateEldredge • The heap manager can ask the OS for 1 GB of RAM, even though the vector is using 200 MB.  Much later when the vector grows, and grows again, it may trip the the fault despite the heap manager thinking it has 1 GB of RAM for the heap because the OS itself is out of RAM to fulfill its RAM commitment (because it over-committed — on such OSs that allow over-commit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely system dependent.

However, on typical desktop and server systems, allocations via `new` in a C++ application are allocations of virtual memory.  If the system has swap space, then it is entirely possible to allocate more virtual memory than the size of physical RAM, so your #2 is closer to the truth.

Of course your vector cannot grow to fill *all* of physical memory plus swap, because some is needed for the OS itself, the rest of your program, other processes running on the system, etc.  The system might be configured to impose other limits, such as a fixed limit on the amount of virtual memory available to any one process or user, and it might also reserve some amount of memory for system-critical uses.

Comment: Based on the wording of the question “inserting elements” wouldn’t you get a different size since the original allocation and new allocation would have to coexist at some point?

Comment: @tinman: Not necessarily.  In some cases it can be possible to extend an existing allocation, rather than having to allocate a whole new block of memory and copy everything over.